# Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

when i tried to change the columns name of a dataframe HG,it turned out that warning:UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access

```
HG=pd.read_csv('HG.csv',header=0,index_col=0)
newname=HG.columns.tolist()
CG=pd.read_csv('CG.csv',header=0,index_col=0)
CG.colunms=newname
```

and the columns name of HG did not change.

Comment: Check your spelling on the assignment. You misspelt columns, which makes pandas try to assign a single column to that name.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains:

- `newname=HG.columns.tolist()` - create *newname* as a list of column
  names in *HG* (*.tolist()* is actually not needed).
- `CG.colunms=newname` - you probably attempt set column names in
  **CG** to the list copied from *HG*, but instead of *colunms* write
  *columns* (wrong sequence of letters).

So there is no surprise that columns name in HG did not change.
Nowhere in your code you attempt to change them.
And to change names in **CG** make the above correction.